# Parsing CSV Values in Bash

Tags: bash, csv

I am trying to write a Bash script that will read a particular csv, and move files based on the values of a column in that csv. However, when I do so it treats everything as false and does not move the files despite the fact that I know for sure it should be reading roughly one in five lines as true.

The code is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=filename.csv

while IFS=, read -a csv_line;
    do
    EMAIL="${csv_line[1]}" #identify the filename
    HASVAL="${csv_line[62]}" #should be either 1 or 0
    if [ -e "$EMAIL" ]
    then
        echo "detected"
        if [ "$HASVAL" = "1" ]
        then
            mv "$EMAIL" /home/targetdirectory
            echo "moved"
        fi
    fi
done < $FILE
```

I cannot see what is wrong with this script. It only prints "detected", never prints "moved" and does not move the files, so I suspect it is not matching the text correctly. Is it possible that I am reading the contents of a csv wrong and its possible for not all values in a csv to be a string? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Thank you for any help you can give.

EDIT: replacing the offending if statement with
     [ "$HASVAL" -eq 1 ]

gives me

```
detected 
:  integer expression expected
```

on every line so I'm not sure integer comparison will work either.

EDIT: As discussed below, it looks like the problem has been solved. The .csv had DOS endings, and since I was looking at the last column it wouldn't match properly, and the last column had to be trimmed of '/r' so it could actually match it to a proper string. Thanks to everybody for the assistance.

Comment: Have you tried echoing the value of `$HASVAL` before you test it to confirm that it is 0 or 1? Are you sure 62 is the right field?

Comment: I have, and its printing a variety of 0s and 1s.

Comment: Check the output of `echo "${HASVAL}x"`.

Comment: It prints x onto ever line.

Comment: You appear to have DOS line endings in the CSV file. Either remove them with `dos2unix`, or trim the variable with `HASVAL=${HASVAL%$'\r'}` before testing it.

Comment: This looks like it works. Thanks again, much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Edit: best practices suggest using double [[ ]] and double equals for your if statement. Also have you verified you are comparing String values or should you be doing an integer comparison.

Comment: No. `=` is the string equality operator for the `test` command.

Comment: Just tried this and it didn't change anything. I believe the above poster is correct in that = is the correct operator for testing.

Comment: I tried replacing the if statement with
    [ "$HASVAL" -eq 1 ] but it gave me the response ": integer expression expected"

Comment: @g.grinovski That would indicate `HASVAL` ends with an invisible character; is field 62 the last field by any chance? Your CSV file may have DOS line endings, meaning `HASVAL` is (say) `1\r`, not `1`.

Comment: @rmeier Best practice aside, your edit would function identically to the code he already has.

Comment: 62 is the last column, yes. Should I be trying to match HASVAL to 1/r rather than 1?